# Disable drag'n'drop from a level to another one

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

I've a treeview formed from [jstree](/questions/tagged/jstree) and I'd like to disable drag'n'drop node from a level to another. Let's take an example:

- Branch 1

  - leaf 1
  - leaf 2
  - leaf 3
- Branch 2

  - leaf 4
  - leaf 5
- Branch 3

  - leaf 6
  - leaf 7
- Branch 4

  - leaf 8

---

I want the user to be able to move branch/re-order leafs & re-order branches but not promote a `leaf` as a `branch` or demote a `branch` as a `leaf`.

I've started to take a look at the file `jstree.dnd.js` to change the comportment but it's out of my league unfortunately.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the jstree `types` plugin. Just include it in your config `plugins` array. Then configure your nodes accordingly (to assign a type to a node make sure it has a `type` property in the JSON).

Here is an example config:

```
"types" : {
    "#" : { // the root node can have only "branch" children
        "valid_children" : ["branch"]
    },
    "branch" : { // any "branch" can only have "leaf" children
        "valid_children" : ["leaf"]
    },
    "leaf" : { // "leaf" typed nodes can not have any children
        "valid_children" : []
    }
},
```

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/560/

You can read more on the types plugin in the repo and on the docs page.

Keep in mind you can use the `core.check_callback` function and avoid using the types plugin - it will give you full manual control but is a bit more complicated to use. I can go into detail if the above does not work for you for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The solution without using the types plugin is indeed much simpler, IMHO. You only have to check for the parent id:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'check_callback' : function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            if (operation === 'move_node' && node.parent !== node_parent.id) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    },
    'plugins': ['dnd']
});
```